# how to link a field from a table to match an expression in a column?

Tags: sql, ms-access

In a davg formula, in the condition section, how to match a field in a table with a formula in a query.

In the below example, I want to avg all the numbers of [dec10], given its category is matching with the [class]

My current formula which is not working is:

```
Davg(“[dec10]”,”prct change”,”[Category] = [Class]“)
```

The error I am receiving is **“Microsoft Access cannot find the name [Class] you entered into the expression”**

I can achieve my desired results through:

```
IIf([Class]=”Retail”,Davg(“[dec10]”,”prct change”,”[category] = ‘retail’ “),
IIf([Class]=”Banks”,Davg(“[dec10]”,”prct change”,”[category] = ‘banks’ “), etc…))
```

However I have more than 100 classes and the size will not fit in the formula.

Any idea anyone pls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that you actually want

```
Davg("[dec10]","prct change","[Category] = '" & [Class] & "'")
```